# Banach spaces $X^*=Y^*$ implies $X=Y$?

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach space. If $X^*$ is isometry to $Y^*$, then $X$ is isometry to $Y$? Here $^*$ means the dual space.

---

If one of $X$ and $Y$ is reflective,the answer is affirmative. Here is my proof. (“=” means isometry)Suppose $X$ is reflective, then $Y^*=X^*$ which is reflective, so $Y^{**}$ is reflective. The classical embedding $Y \mapsto Y^{**}$ shows $Y$ is (isometry to) a closed subspace of $Y^{**}$. Hence $Y$ is reflective by the result that any closed subspace of reflexive space is reflective. So $Y=X^{**}=Y^{**}=Y$.

For non-reflective case, I try to prove but failed. And I guess this claim is false. But It seems to be difficult to give counter examples.
Can someone give me some hint or references? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple counterexample is
$$
X = c = \{ \text{convergent sequences}\}
$$
and
$$
Y = c_0 = \{ \text{null sequences}\}.
$$
Then, one can check that
$$
X^* = \ell^1 = Y^*
$$
(isometric isomorphisms).

The spaces $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic but not isometrically isomorphic (look at the extremal points of the unit ball).

Answer (score 1):

There exists a Banach space $X$ such that $X^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell¹$, but $X$ is not even isomorphic to $c_0$. In fact these spaces are actively studied in a subfield of Functional Analysis called "pre-duals of $\ell^1$".  See, for example:

[1] *Bessaga, Czeslaw; Pełczyński, Aleksander*, [**Spaces of continuous functions. IV: On isomorphical classification of spaces of continuous functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/sm-19-1-53-62), Stud. Math. 19, 53-62 (1960). [ZBL0094.30303](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0094.30303).

[2] *Benyamini, Y.; Lindenstrauss, J.*, [**A predual of (l_1) which is not isomorphic to a C(K) space**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02762798), Isr. J. Math. 13, 246-254 (1972). [ZBL0253.46044](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0253.46044).